# Questions on Testing for Heteroskedasticity/Autocorrelation (statistics)

Tags: statistics, economics

[image: img]

I just wanted to confirm and see your opinions:

a) True

b) True

c) False

Comment: cannot see the image, can you post the text/formulae directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) False. Let us say that you used some incorrect weights matrix $B$, then
$$
\hat{\beta} = (X'BX)^{-1}X'By,
$$ 
as such
$$
E(\hat{\beta}|X) = (X'BX)^{-1}X'BE(y)=(X'BX)^{-1}X'B(X\beta + E\epsilon)=\beta.
$$
Thus the weights matrix does not effect the bias of the estimators (however, it surely effects the variance and hence the inference).

2) True. Apply the same logic as at $(1)$. Autocorellation can be viewed as  a specification of the covariance matrix, hence as long as $E\epsilon = 0$, it does not effect the expectation of the estimators.

3) False. E.g., Ljung-Box is another valid test for the same task.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for clarifying! I also posted this question yesterday and haven't gotten an answer yet thanks again man http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/272365/evaluating-the-bias-variance-of-a-transformed-model-estimator